# How to avoid reentrancy in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angularjs-directive, reentrancy

Bootstrap selectpicker hides original select and creates additional element filling it with options from the select. However when using ngOptions selectpicker doesn't automatically updates itself.

So I've created a directive which listens for ngOptions collection changes and calls `element.selectpicker()`

It works fine if no filtering is applied for ngOptions. Otherwise filering function returns new array each time it is called what causes $watch callback to fire which recreates selectpicker. Angular detects DOM has changed and starts new digest cycle effectively infinitely looping the process. After 10 iterations Angular as expected throws exception.

I need to temporarily unsubscribe from the watch when creating selectpicker und later subscribe again when digest cycles are finished. Is it possible?

**Update1**

Thougt a little more and now have an Idea to try. Filter defines a factory returning filtering function thus I can use captured array to store filtered content - the reference won't change so listener will fire only when contents of collection changes.

Comment: I know this isn't exactly an answer to your question but you could always just go the custom route for your drop downs and avoid the problem altogether... again, shameless (starting to become shameful) plug -_- http://matterickson.me/dropdowns_selectboxes/

Answer (score 0):

About temporarily stop watching:

`$watch` always returns you unwatch function afaik:

```
var stopW = $scope.$watch('data', process);
stopW(); //anywhere
```

Also small advice.  Sometimes you don't want to compare '===' when watching.
Try to use function, detects anything changed:

```
$watch(function(){return $scope.data.list;}, process);
```

or even:

```
$watch(function(){return JSON.stringify($scope.data);}, process);
```

The last one should completely ignore array recreates by your filter.